# State logger for optimization problems

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, template-meta-programming, benchmarking

I am working on a C++ project for solving a class of optimization problems. The project will be header-only, and for now, I would like to stay with C++11 (so, not fold-expressions).

To be able to support some basic logging functionality, I have started writing the below logger class. Any comment/feedback is welcome. However, I would like to ask specifically about your suggestions on how to restructure the code, if at all, to make it more efficient.

```cpp
#ifndef LOGGER_HPP_
#define LOGGER_HPP_

#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

namespace utility {
namespace logger {

template <class float_t, bool log_x_v, bool log_g_v> struct logger_t {
  template <class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
  void operator()(const std::size_t k, const float_t fval, InputIt1 xbegin,
                  InputIt1 xend, InputIt2 gbegin, InputIt2 gend) {
    tend = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto telapsed =
        std::chrono::duration<float_t, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>(
            tend - tstart);
    iterations.push_back(k);
    times.push_back(telapsed.count());
    fvalues.push_back(fval);
    log_x(xbegin, xend, std::integral_constant<bool, log_x_v>{});
    log_g(gbegin, gend, std::integral_constant<bool, log_g_v>{});
    tstart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  }

private:
  template <class InputIt>
  void log_x(InputIt xbegin, InputIt xend, std::true_type) {
    xvalues.emplace_back(xbegin, xend);
  }
  template <class InputIt> void log_x(InputIt, InputIt, std::false_type) {}
  template <class InputIt>
  void log_g(InputIt gbegin, InputIt gend, std::true_type) {
    gvalues.emplace_back(gbegin, gend);
  }
  template <class InputIt> void log_g(InputIt, InputIt, std::false_type) {}

  std::vector<std::size_t> iterations;
  std::vector<float_t> times;
  std::vector<float_t> fvalues;
  std::vector<std::vector<float_t>> xvalues, gvalues;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> tstart{
      std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()},
      tend;
};

template <class float_t> using value = logger_t<float_t, false, false>;
template <class float_t> using decision = logger_t<float_t, true, false>;
template <class float_t> using gradient = logger_t<float_t, false, true>;
template <class float_t> using full = logger_t<float_t, true, true>;

} // namespace logger
} // namespace utility

#endif
```

Basically, the class is *not* complete, yet. I will be adding iterator support, read/write csv/binary functionality and some locking mechanism, later on, to be able to support thread-safe logging of values inside the logger.

Specifically, what I would like to ask is if I need to have some level of abstraction to make the unused private member variables disappear. The tag dispatch on `log_x` and `log_g` member functions seem to be OK when it comes to optimizing out the empty function calls, I hope. But then, when there is no logging needed for `x` and `g`, private member variables `xvalues` and `gvalues` are redundant. Should I care about them, or should I leave it as is for the sake of maintainability and ease of reading the code?

Comment: Isn't "float_t" a confusing name for a template parameter?

Comment: This is something I have heard before. OK, I need to change the name to something like `real_t`. The thing is, `float_t` will majorly be either of `float` or `double`, and `real_t` is a real number type, which includes integers. That was the intuition, but I need to find a better name for it, apparently. Thanks for the heads-up! :)

Comment: you could call it value_t

Comment: Agreed. I have started changing the name here, then ;)

Comment: You shouldn't update the code in the question with people reviews, it's better if you leave it as it is so other people can give you their advice ;) I'm quite new to c++ so don't listen too much to me hehe. Welcome to Code Review by the way!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome :) I will revert back the changes. Actually, a bit off-topic as a comment, but I would like to discuss your OpenOL sometime...

Comment: Thanks @MathiasEttinger for rolling back. I was gonna do that as per WooWapDaBug's suggestion.

Comment: @ArdaAytekin It's just that we have a system in place to [detect possible answer invalidation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43121550#43121550) and keeping answers consistent with the question is rather important for their value. We usually rollback the question even before commenting because we have no way to know when/if OP is going to. No harm meant. (Besides I didn't pay attention to the comments and didn't saw WooWapDaBug's one.)

Comment: Thank you once more for the clarification. No hard feelings :) I also do understand your policy regarding invalidation. I will be more careful the next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a better name for the template argument `float_t`, maybe `value_t`

Maybe you could combine both log functions as they are very similar:

```
template <typename Container, typename InputIt>
void log(Container &c, InputIt begin, InputIt end, std::true_type) {
    c.emplace_back(begin, end);
  }
```

Comment: Most likely I will have to have `Container& c` in the signature. That's nice, and that will definitely make my code shorter. However, still the question remains: what about the `xvalues` or `gvalues` when they are not needed?

Comment: They would be empty vectors, would that be a big problem for you? There is probably a simpler solution. My opinion is that the code looks a little bit over complicated, why do you need the `bool log_x_v, bool log_g_v` template parameters, what are you gaining with it?

Comment: Maybe my design choice is wrong, but I thought I would benefit from compile-time known parameters to implement just the enough functionality needed. I mean, if the user chooses to go for only `value` function logging, the call to `log` (in your suggestion) will get optimized out. no run-time checking whatsoever. I agree that the empty vectors should not be a big problem when one logs a couple of data points... In the end, they are simply like pointers, especially when compared to some couple of data points.